# Changing both width, height and transform simultaneously cause the weird transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

If I change the `width`, `height` and `transform` properties simultaneously it produces pretty weird transition. The example is below. Look at the rectangle and its position relative to the red line.

[The demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dvoy04bt/3/).

[image]

I know replacing `transform` property by `left` and `top` properties fix it, but it's not the solution in my case because it produces performance and other issues.

**UPDATE:** the `scale` transform is not solution, because in the real case proportions can be changed and the internal content should not be affected by scale transformation. –

```js
const states = [{
    height: '250px',
    width: '500px',
    transform: 'translate(50px, 50px)'
  },
  {
    height: '150px',
    width: '250px',
    transform: 'translate(175px, 100px)'
  },
]

let currentState = 0;

function updateState() {
  const box = document.querySelector(".box");

  const state = states[currentState];

  currentState = (currentState + 1) % states.length

  box.style.height = state.height
  box.style.width = state.width
  box.style.transform = state.transform
}
```

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  background: #AAA;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 1px;
}

.small-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="small-box" style="left: 50%; top:0"></div>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<button class="button" onclick="updateState()">Update State</button>
```

Comment: No weird [`transition`](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/CSS/transition "MDN Web Docs") is happening in your [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dvoy04bt/3/ "JSFiddle"). [*`Preview`*](https://i.imgur.com/qJAPLFF.mp4 "Imgur"). Could you include steps to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it by toggling the state several times. It appears to be inconsistent from one render to the next. Sometimes it looks fine and sometimes it looks like the animated gif in the question.

Comment: @nitrovatter if at all possible, I'd reconsider transitioning `left` and `top` values instead of `transform: translate()` if the transform "wobble" is unacceptable but you still need to set explicit coordinates for some reason. Or, see if you can make @ЖнецЪ 's approach work, which would probably be the way I'd solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change `transform` property on js : `50px` and `100px` is become `calc(300px - 50%)`

`calc(300px - 50%)` is line position minus half of `.box`'s div

```js
const states = [{
    height: '250px',
    width: '500px',
    transform: 'translate(calc(300px - 50%), 50px)'
  },
  {
    height: '150px',
    width: '250px',
    transform: 'translate(calc(300px - 50%), 100px)'
  },
]

let currentState = 0;

function updateState() {
  const box = document.querySelector(".box");

  const state = states[currentState];

  currentState = (currentState + 1) % states.length

  box.style.height = state.height
  box.style.width = state.width
  box.style.transform = state.transform
}
```

```css
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  background: #AAA;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 1px;
}

.small-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="small-box" style="left: 50%; top:0"></div>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
<button class="button" onclick="updateState()">Update State</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it did a trick. How did you get this idea?

Comment: I first tried using variables and changing the origin of `.box`, then got lost and had a stroke of genius

Answer (score 3):

Try this example i did use `transform: scale` instead `transform: translate`. Moved up the `small-box`, because if scaled the `box` itself, `small-box` is scaled too. And did wrap into `flex`.

```js
const states = [
  {
    height: '250px',
    width: '500px',
    // transform: 'translate(50px, 50px)',
  },
  {
    height: '150px',
    width: '250px',
    // transform: 'translate(175px, 100px)',
  },
];

let currentState = 0;

function updateState() {
  const box = document.querySelector('.box');

  const state = states[currentState];

  currentState = (currentState + 1) % states.length;

  box.style.height = state.height;
  box.style.width = state.width;
  box.style.transform = state.transform;
}
```

```css
.wrapper { /* Added */
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.box {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  /* position: absolute; */
  background: #aaa;
  /* left: 0; */
  /* top: 0; */
  transform-origin: top center;
}
.line {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; /* Changed */
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: 1px;
}
.small-box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="small-box" style="left: 50%; top: 0"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <button class="button" onclick="updateState()">Update State</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I truly should noted: `scale` is not solution, because in the real case proportions can be changed. Also, the proportions of the internal content shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Alas, in your example the positioning of the box is lost. It's important. The position may be pretty varied.